# update MYsql with YYmmdd format

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have a query problem in updating date in YYmmdd format. I use Mysql Database

this the query I try to excute

```
update table set DATE(Birthday)=STR_TO_DATE(‘470330’, %Y%m%d) where ID=1;
```

Does anyone know whats the problem with my query?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(Birthday)

Comment: You should actually **read** the error message instead of copy-pasting it here. It's here to _help_ you _fix_ your sql.

Comment: FYI, here's the MySQL `UPDATE` syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table_name set Birthday=STR_TO_DATE('19470330', '%Y%m%d') where ID=1;
```

Corrections:

1. Value can be assigned to column (`Birthday`; not to function: `DATE(Birthday)`)
2. Date format string: `%Y` - four digits year, `%y` - two digits year
3. String literals must by quoted within single `'` or double `"` quotation marks

Comment: it still got the wrong result. it supposed to be updated (1947-03-30).. not (2047-03-30)

Comment: Then use four digits year format: `STR_TO_DATE('19470330', '%Y%m%d')`. Answer corrected.

Comment: the input format is in format YYmmDD. and I cant change it

Comment: @muhnizar JUST CONCATENATE `20` BEFORE THE INPUT STRING!

Answer (score 1):

Format have to be also a string. Here is the [tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/).

```
 STR_TO_DATE('470330','%Y%m%d');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the format arguments in as a string like so:

STR_TO_DATE('470330','%Y%m%d')

Assuming that your column name actually is: "DATE(Birthday)" and you're not attempting to illegally call a date function and that your table name actually is: "table" then:

I'd expect your query to be:

```
update `table` set `DATE(Birthday)`=STR_TO_DATE('470330', '%Y%m%d') where ID=1;
```

or with quotes instead of backticks, depending on how your database is setup.

Comment: @okiharaherbst Please explain; I'm making certain assumptions about  what the OP's table structure is as it's not clear from the question - if I've got completely the wrong end of the stick, I'll remove this answer.

Comment: Here `DATE(Birthday)` refers to the `DATE()` built-in function. The brackets are not integral parts of the field name. MySQL complains at the first syntax error encountered which is this illegal function application. Of course, OP also had to wrap the date format with quotes. The `UPDATE table` is just a poor euphemism for `UPDATE table_name` in my opinion.

Comment: @okiharaherbst I've updated my answer to state the assumptions I've made about what tables and columns are called

Comment: I hadn't seen your closing comment about backticks. Still I believe that anyone who names a field `DATE(Birthday)` shouldn't be allowed to use a computer without supervision.

Comment: The ANSI_QUOTES mode (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) that allows you to use `"` instead of a backticks is however not the default. Therefore I think that your answer should read the other way around with backticks in the query and `"` in the comment. I'll upvote then.